# Custom redirection after checkout based on a custom checkout field in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, orders

I would like 2 redirection links in woocommerce after checkout. The first is the standard checkout link that sends any user to a thank you page. The other would be if they check a box that says they are interested in a membership during checkout. If they are we would like them to be redirected to a membership area.

I found this code for thank you page redirect:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'bbloomer_redirectcustom');
function bbloomer_redirectcustom( $order_id ){
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

    $membership = WHAT FIELD HERE FROM ORDER? // Need a way to set this variable to checkbox true or not.

    $url = 'http://yoursite.com/thank-you'; //Thank you page
    $mem_url = 'http://yoursite.com/members'; // Membership page

    if ( $order->status != 'failed' && !$membership) {
        wp_redirect($url);
        exit;
    } else {
        wp_redirect($mem_url);
        exit;
    }
}
```

I have a way to add the checkbox to the checkout page (using Woo Checkout Field Editor Pro plugin). I just need a way for this code (which I haven't tested yet) to check if the membership field was checked when the order was placed and redirect to another page.

FYI, we are using PayPal as our primary payment gateway. I don't know if this makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody can give you an answer regarding how to get the value of your custom field. You should be able to get it yourself looking in wp_postmeta database table *(for an order ID where you have used this checkbox)*. Then you will use **`get_post_meta()`** function to get it (like in my answer below).

Now you don't need a plugin to output a custom checkbox field in your checkout page. you can do it with some easy custom code (you have just to tell in what location you want it).

To make a custom redirection, **`woocommerce_thankyou`** **is not the right hook**.

Below you will find some code that will output a custom checkbox (just after the order notes), that will save the value when the order is submitted. If the checkbox is checked, the customer will be redirected to your special page **"members"**.

You don't need an other redirection, as by default after submitting an order, customer is redirected to thankyou page.

Here is that code *(commented)*:

```
// Add the custom checkout field
add_filter( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'add_membership_checkbox_checkout_field' );
function add_membership_checkbox_checkout_field( $checkout ) {

    woocommerce_form_field( 'membership_interested', array(
        'type'        => 'checkbox',
        'class'       => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
        'label'       => __('I am interested in a membership plan (optional)', 'woocommerce'),
        'required'    => false,
    ), $checkout->get_value( 'membership_interested' ));
}

// Save the custom checkout field in the order meta
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'save_membership_checkbox_checkout_field' );
function save_membership_checkbox_checkout_field( $order_id ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['membership_interested'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_membership_interested', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['membership_interested'] ) );
    }
}

// Custom conditional_redirect on thank you page
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'thankyou_custom_conditional_redirect');
function thankyou_custom_conditional_redirect(){
    // Only in thank you page
    if ( ! is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' ) ) return;

    global $wp;

    $order_id =  intval( str_replace( 'checkout/order-received/', '', $wp->request ) );

    $membership = get_post_meta( $order_id, '_membership_interested', true );

    if ( $membership ) {
        wp_redirect(home_url( '/members/' ) );
        exit;
    } else return;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested on Woocommerce 3+ and works.

> **Last thing:** You will certainly need to add a condition in the function that adds the custom checkbox field (in checkout), to hide it when a membership product is in cart.